# Fastparse runs out of memory for simple rules

Tags: scala, fastparse

I wrote following parser using `fastparse` library to get words in pairs. On execution it parses using `parsePair` properly. But for `parseMultiPairs` it goes into 100% CPU usage and then exitsx with `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
import fastparse.*, MultiLineWhitespace.*

case class Pair(a: String, b: String)

def parsePair[$: P]: P[Pair] = P(CharIn("a-z").repX.! ~ CharIn("a-z").repX.!).map(Pair(_, _))

def parsePairs[$: P]: P[Seq[Pair]] = P(parsePair.rep ~ End)

println(parse("gnu linux", parsePair(_)))
println(parse("gnu linux", parsePairs(_)))
```

I thought maybe I am not writing the grammar correctly. So I wrote similar grammar in `parsy` library of Python as:

```
from parsy import *

word = regex(r'[a-z]+')
pair = word.sep_by(regex(r' +'), min=2, max=2)
pairs = pair.sep_by(regex(r'[ \n]+'))

print(word.parse('hello'))
print(pair.parse('hello world'))
print(pairs.parse('hello world hey there\ngood bye'))
```

It works as expected and is able to parse all inputs. What change do I need with `fastparse` to make it work?

Comment: Did you try to run a profiler to maybe get a hint at what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a reply from Haoyi themself [here on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/632150470000902164/940067748103487558/1194431774311338055). Issue with my `fastparse` spec was my definition of word as `CharIn("a-z").repX` which is 0 or more characters, instead of `CharIn("a-z").repX(1)` which is 1 or more characters.

Following is the complete working code:

```
object Test extends App:
    import fastparse.*, MultiLineWhitespace.*

    case class Pair(a: String, b: String)

    def parsePair[$: P]: P[Pair] = P(CharIn("a-z").repX(1).! ~ CharIn("a-z").repX(1).!).map(Pair(_, _))

    def parseMultiPairs[$: P]: P[Seq[Pair]] = P(parsePair.rep ~ End)

    println(parse("gnu linux", parsePair(_)))
    println(parse("hello world hey there\ngood bye", parseMultiPairs(_)))
end Test
```